# Can't print value to label in Swift 4. Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, api, label

I have been working on a personal project, and have made a weather checking app for iOS in swift 4, I have the OpenWeatherMap API working and parsing JSON data through, and I can get their values in the console. Now I want to simply set the value of the Label 'T' to be equal to the value of 'ggtemp', which is the current temperature.  I have tried placing it in an if statement, "if T != nil" do this etc, but I can't get anything to work. Help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Code below:

```
import UIKit



    struct Coordinate : Decodable {
        let lat, lon : Double?
    }

    struct Weather : Decodable {
        let id : Int?
        let main, description, icon : String?
    }

    struct Sys : Decodable {
        let type, id : Int?
        let sunrise, sunset : Date?
        let message : Double?
        let country : String?
    }

    struct Main : Decodable {
        let temp, tempMin, tempMax : Double?
        let pressure, humidity : Int?
    }

    struct Wind : Decodable {
        let speed : Double?
        let deg : Int?
    }

    struct MyWeather : Decodable {
        let coord : Coordinate?
        let cod, visibility, id : Int?
        let name : String?
        let base : String?
        let weather : [Weather]?
        let sys : Sys?
        let main : Main?
        let wind : Wind?
        let dt : Date?
    }
    class ViewController: UIViewController {


        //Labels
        @IBOutlet weak var thumidity: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var tmain: UILabel!
           @IBOutlet  weak var ttemp: UILabel!
           @IBOutlet weak var tspeed: UILabel!

           @IBOutlet weak var gmain: UILabel!
           @IBOutlet weak var gtemp: UILabel!
           @IBOutlet weak var ghumidity: UILabel!
           @IBOutlet weak var gspeed: UILabel!
          @IBOutlet  weak var T: UILabel!


        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()



            guard let APIUrl = URL(string: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Crowland&appid=e7b2054dc37b1f464d912c00dd309595&units=Metric") else { return }

            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: APIUrl) { data, response, error in
                guard let data = data else { return }

                let decoder = JSONDecoder()


                do {
                    let weatherData = try decoder.decode(MyWeather.self, from: data)


                    if let gmain = weatherData.weather?.description {
                        print(gmain)
                       // tmain.text = String(describing: gmain)
                    }


                    if let gspeed = weatherData.wind?.speed {
                        print(gspeed)
                        //speed.text = String(gspeed)
                    }

                    if let ghumidity = weatherData.main?.humidity {
                        print(ghumidity)
                    }


                        if let ggtemp = weatherData.main?.temp {

                            print(ggtemp, "TEST")

                                self.T.text? = String (ggtemp)


                    }

                } catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
                }.resume()
        }
    }
```

Comment: You either need to associate your @IBOutlets in interface builder or initialize them in your controller. Self.T == none

Answer (score 0):

What about if you write self.T.text without question mark (that means it's an optional or it can be nil)?

Answer (score 0):

Your label might not be registered with interface builder. Check your outlets on that view from storyboard and make sure it's there - because the value of text is optional, but not the label itself (force upwrapped)(!)

Set a breakpoint on the invocation of that labels value and check to see if that label itself is not nil